# In an HTML table, how can I make vertical lines visible (the same kind as the default horizontal ones)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-6

Given that I'm allowed to use static JS and HTML tags (only those supported by IE6), how can I make vertical lines visible (the same kind as the default horizontal ones*)?

*In a default HTML table you can see (subtle) horizontal lines. I need vertical lines in the same style as those horizontal lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about doing something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/b7WK8/1/

```
td{border:1px solid #000;}
```

Comment: Not really. I was looking for the subtle (gray) default lines that are displayed on a HTML table.  However, your solution is better than nothing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marking as deleted since RULES is deprecated...

<del>Set `RULES` attribute along with `BORDER` attribute for the table.
i.e:

    
    .
    .
    .</del>

Comment: I think the `rules` attribute is deprecated. It's not on the list: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#attributes-1

Comment: Yep, its usage is recommended against: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features